# How to remove comma from column of Abstracttablemodel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, abstracttablemodel

```
public class WebCrmSearchOutputTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Vector iTotalRows = null;

    public WebCrmSearchOutputTableModel() {
        super();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int pColumn)
    {
        String[] colheads;
        colheads = new String[]
             {
                Language.getMessage("TIT0007"), //Channel       
                Language.getMessage("TIT00038"), //Old Loyalty No
                Language.getMessage("TIT00039"),// ULP No
                Language.getMessage("TIT00040"), // First Name  
                Language.getMessage("TIT00041"), // Last Name
                Language.getMessage("TNR036"),//Town/City   
                Language.getMessage("TIT00042"),//DOB
                Language.getMessage("COR0756"),//Mob no     
                Language.getMessage("TIT00043"),// LandLine
                Language.getMessage("COR0747"),//Email      
                Language.getMessage("TS00034"),//Loyalty Points
                Language.getMessage("XE99936"),// Home Store
                Language.getMessage("TNR037"),//Address1    
                Language.getMessage("TNR038"),//Address2    
                Language.getMessage("TIT00045"),//Current Tier
                Language.getMessage("TIT00046"),//Enrollment Date
                Language.getMessage("XE99038"),//Customer Number

                //Start-BNIKA01 for CR in ULP for Mapping State parameter on 12-10-2012
                ""//State
                //End-BNIKA01 for CR in ULP for Mapping State parameter on 12-10-2012


                //START BSASH05- TNS0115 - Redemption of Mobile - GV
                ,""//Blocked
                ,""//Birthday Disc
                ,""//Anniversary Disc
                //END BSASH05- TNS0115 - Redemption of Mobile - GV
            }; 
        return colheads[pColumn];
    }

    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
        //Start-BNIKA01 for CR in ULP for Mapping State parameter on 12-10-2012
        //return 17;
//      return 18;
        //End-BNIKA01 for CR in ULP for Mapping State parameter on 12-10-2012

        //START BSASH05- TNS0115 - Redemption of Mobile - GV
        return 21;
        //END BSASH05- TNS0115 - Redemption of Mobile - GV
    }
    public int getRowCount() 
    {
        return getTotalRows().size();
    }
    public Vector getTotalRows() 
    {
        return iTotalRows;
    }
    public Object getValueAt(int pRow, int pCol) 
    {
        return ((Object[]) getTotalRows().elementAt(pRow))[pCol];
    }
    public void setTotalRows(Vector pTotalRows) 
    {
        iTotalRows = pTotalRows;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean the commas in `colheads = new String[]`?

Comment: hi actually the values getting displayed are  with commas in columns

Comment: can you post a screenshot? and maybe have a look at the `language` class then and what exactly it return with `getMessage`

Comment: Language.getMessage just returns the column header actually the values in the row here are coming with comma and image posting is not allowed as i have less reputation as am new to the site

Comment: then you should have a look at why it returns the values with commas. this has nothing to do with the code you posted

Comment: actually the values coming are not comma seperated but there is some problem with the rendering

Comment: so if you print out 1 value there is no comma in it? maybe show the code where you actually set the column header

Comment: can u please suggest how to do super.super call

Comment: i know in java explicitly super.super is not allowed but this is going to solve my problem completely

Comment: maybe implement in the first super class a method which again calls a method with super?

Answer (score 0):

> actually the values coming are not comma seperated but there is some problem with the rendering

I doubt the problem is with the rendering. Renderers don't just magically display a "," for no reason.

The problem would be with your `getColumnNames(...)` method. A couple of points:

1. Don't populate the values in your array every time the method is called. The columns names should be loaded when the class is constructed.
2. Your `Language.getMessage(...)` would be the problem. The method is returning a String containing a column. So you need to create wrapper method that you use to remove the "," from the String before you add the value to the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the rendering
after making some code changes for rendering and making java realize that the column is string and not int it started to work